# Subtracting subject-specific grouped data according to a categorical variable

Tags: r, difference, longitudinal

I have the following data, where:
*PseudoID* = ID, *Trim_SSW* = trimester of pregnancy (1, 2 or 3), *weight* = subject weight at time point SSW and *SSW* = gestational weeks

```
structure(list(PseudoID = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L), Trim_SSW = c("T1", 
"T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3"), weight = c(120.8, 
120.9, 120.8, 122.2, 122.5, 125, 124.6, 126.6, 126.4, 126.7, 
126.7, 128, 129.3, 101.7, 100.5, 100.2, 101.7, 104.2, 104.2, 
105.6), SSW = c(8L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 23L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 18L, 22L, 25L, 29L)), .Names = c("PseudoID", 
"Trim_SSW", "weight", "SSW"), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 15L, 12L, 
17L, 16L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 18L, 20L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 42L, 
43L, 48L, 31L), class = "data.frame")
```

For each ID, I want to see the weight gain in each trimester. Therefore, I need to find the difference between the last measurement and the first measurement in T1, T2 and T3 separately. Where only 1 measurement is available in a trimester, I want to put NA. I assume that making 3 new variables (T1gain, T2gain, T3gain) would ease further calculations.

I have seen a similar post here but it did not answer my question fully and I was asked to make a new post.

Comment: Not clear how the output should be. Is it a new data frame with columns: ID, trimester, T1gain, T2gain, T3gain? Or add the gain information in the original data frame?

Comment: @AntoniosK Yes, a new data frame with columns: ID, trimester, T1gain, T2gain, T3gain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

structure(list(PseudoID = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 
1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L), Trim_SSW = c("T1", 
"T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3"), weight = c(120.8, 
120.9, 120.8, 122.2, 122.5, 125, 124.6, 126.6, 126.4, 126.7, 
126.7, 128, 129.3, 101.7, 100.5, 100.2, 101.7, 104.2, 104.2, 
105.6), SSW = c(8L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 23L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 18L, 22L, 25L, 29L)), .Names = c("PseudoID", 
"Trim_SSW", "weight", "SSW"), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 15L, 12L, 
17L, 16L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 18L, 20L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 42L, 
43L, 48L, 31L), class = "data.frame") -> dt

dt %>%
  group_by(PseudoID, Trim_SSW) %>%                                       # for each ID and trimester
  summarise(Weight_gain = weight[length(weight)] - weight[1],            # get last - first weights
            NumRows = n(),                                               # count number of rows/observations
            Weight_gain = ifelse(NumRows == 1, NA, Weight_gain)) %>%     # flag with NA if there's only 1 row
  select(-NumRows) %>%                                                   # remove unecessary column
  mutate(Trim_SSW = paste0(Trim_SSW, "_gain")) %>%                       # change the names
  ungroup() %>%                                                          # forget the grouping
  spread(Trim_SSW, Weight_gain)                                          # reshape

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   PseudoID T1_gain T2_gain T3_gain
# *    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1001     0.1     1.7     4.3
# 2     1002    -1.5     2.5      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out! I'm using `dplyr` and `data.table`, both of which are powerful packages. I don't know the exact output you want, so you can compare the two outputs of `b` and `c` to see which meets your needs.

```
# doing the calculations                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          17L, 16L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 18L, 20L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 42L, 
library(dplyr)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       43L, 48L, 31L), class = "data.frame")
b <- a %>%
  group_by(PseudoID, Trim_SSW) %>%
  summarize(gain = last(weight) - first(weight))

# reshaping data from long to wide format
library(data.table)
c <- setDT(b)
c <- dcast(c, PseudoID ~ Trim_SSW, value.var = "gain")

# rename column names
names(c)[2:4] <- c("T1_gain", "T2_gain", "T3_gain")


# comparing the two outputs
> b
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   PseudoID [?]
  PseudoID Trim_SSW  gain
     <int>    <chr> <dbl>
1     1001       T1   0.1
2     1001       T2   1.7
3     1001       T3   4.3
4     1002       T1  -1.5
5     1002       T2   2.5
6     1002       T3   0.0

> c
   PseudoID T1_gain T2_gain T3_gain
1:     1001     0.1     1.7     4.3
2:     1002    -1.5     2.5     0.0
```

Of course, if you prefer `b`, make sure you change the class types of the variables accordingly (factor, factor, numeric, in that order)